# SQL select 2 columns A and B but output A sorted by B

Tags: sql, sorting

say I have a db with 2 columns

```
Col1   |   Col2
VW     |   2011
FIAT   |   2015
CHEVY  |   2010
```

...I want to output **just** Col1 based off the years in Col 2 in Desc order (2015,2011,2010)

Final Output requested:

```
FIAT
VW
CHEVY
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Col1 FROM dbo.Table1 ORDER BY Col2 DESC;
```